# Is Stud_PE a legitimate program?

Tags: patching

I have a binary that crashes at certain user input, and after using Ghidra and x64Dbg to understand what's happening, I'd like to just fix the problem. I can use Ghidra to NOP the function call that is crashing the program, but if I could make just some small changes to the function I could fix the problem.

I found a few posts referencing a tool called Stud_PE from a questionable site (https://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html). I downloaded it and used Virus Total to tell me if it thought it was malicious and it came back with some hits.

Is this program legit? Is it filled with malware? Are there any alternatives (even paid) besides this option to add room to drop in assembly code to binary?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's legitimate. I've used it myself a few years ago and haven't had any problems.